# Facebook Graph: Match friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to see if two facebook users are friends. I could've used graph api **.../user1/friends/user2** but instead of actual user ids I have scoped ids (facebook js sdk returns scoped ids). So how can I use user scoped ids to see if they are friends using Facebook js sdk?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This should still work with App Scoped IDs: `/me/friends/[app-scoped-id]`

It also works with two different App Scoped IDs: `/[id1]/friends/[id2]`

I just tried it with v2.5 of the Graph API in the API Explorer and got the friend with the App Scoped ID. If it returns nothing, the users are no friends - or they did not authorize your App with the `user_friends` permission.

Of course both users must have authorized your App for this, for privacy reasons.